# Is struct dot style initializers supported in C++ Builder 32bit?

Tags: c++builder

The following initializer is supported in Embarcadero C++ Builder 32bit?

```
struct test_s test = { .first = 1, .third = 3, .second = 2 };
```

It works on the 64bit target platform however I think it not works on 32bit platform.
I tried it in C++ Builder 10.1 .

Comment: Which 32bit compiler? There are 3 now - bcc32, bcc32c, and bcc32x.  Designated Initializers is a C++20 feature, and Embarcadero does not have a C++20 compiler yet, so I'm surprised you say this works in 64bit, as the clang-based compilers support only up to C++17. [Modern C++ Features Supported by RAD Studio Clang-enhanced C++ Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Modern_C%2B%2B_Features_Supported_by_RAD_Studio_Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next code

```
struct test_s
{
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    test_s test = {.first = 1, .second = 2, .third = 3};

    return 0;
}
```

compiles with C++ Builder 10.4.1 under Windows 64 bit platform (BCC64/Clang) as well as under Windows 32 bit platform if "Use classic Borland compiler" option is unchecked (BCC32C/Clang). Both compilers are based on LLVM ver. 5.0.2.